# change color in two components using a button click

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

so like the title says.I have a button in books component, when it's clicked a div color in books component and another div in navbar component should change it's color.

**- this is the books component :**

```
export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {

  status:boolean = true ;
  color:boolean ;

  constructor(private colorService:ShareColorService) { }
  
  changeTheme(){
    this.status = !this.status ;
  } ;

  public send():void{
    this.colorService.updateColor(this.status) ; 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**this is the service code that passes data value from books to navbar component :**

```
export class ShareColorService {
  
  private notifs = new Subject<boolean>() ;
  
  constructor() { }

  public getColor(): Observable<boolean>{
    return this.notifs.asObservable() ; 
    }

  public updateColor(color: boolean){
    this.notifs.next(color) ;
  }
}
```

**and this is navbar component :**

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public navbarNewColor:boolean ;
  public subscription: Subscription ;
  constructor(private colorService:ShareColorService) { }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void{
    this.subscription.unsubscribe() ;
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.colorService.getColor().subscribe(color => this.navbarNewColor = color) ;
  console.log("navbarnewcolor :",this.navbarNewColor) ;
  }  
}
```

**ternary operator that controls the ngclass to change color :**

```
<nav  class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" [ngClass]="navbarNewColor ? 'bg-light':'bg-dark'">
```

Comment: How have you declared the Service? (make sure there is just one instance) Also, we get the problem, but what *exactly* doesn't work?

Comment: when i click the button only the color of the div's books component change. nothing happens at the other component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually assigning the value to the `navbarNewColor` variable by subscribing, you could use a more reactive approach here:

```
export class NavbarComponent {
  
  public navbarClass$ = this.colorService.getColor().pipe(
    map(isLightMode => isLightMode ? 'bg-light' : 'bg-dark')
  );

  constructor(private colorService:ShareColorService) { }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" [ngClass]="(navbarClass$ | async)">
```

This should give you an idea!

Comment: i love ur approach, but my problem is to understand why it's not working more than how to make it work and it still puzzles me

Comment: Is your component using `OnPush` change detection strategy? Also If you can add a min reproducible sandbox it would be easier to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: no, i'm using (click) event to detect any changes. after that a variable will toggle from true to false, then send this variable's value (status:boolean) to the other component.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer!

As I was expecting it was obvious. The service method that updates `div` color by sending the button click value (true or false) was only running once because it was outside of the click button function.

```
changeTheme(){
    this.status = !this.status;
    this.colorService.updateColor(this.status); 
    console.log(this.status);
}
```